# PyCharm crashing immediately on OS X

Tags: macos, pycharm

I'm new to python and PyCharm. I have both CE and Pro running on my machine: OS X 10.10

Community Edition runs just fine, but when I open the Professional Edition it opens, sits in the launcher for a few seconds then closes.

I opened up my console, cleared it and ran PyCharm again. Here's all the output:

```
pycharm[13752]: Value of PYCHARM_JDK: (null)
pycharm[13752]: fullFileName is: /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/bin/pycharm.vmoptions
pycharm[13752]: fullFileName exists: /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/bin/pycharm.vmoptions
pycharm[13752]: Value of PYCHARM_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
pycharm[13752]: Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/bin/pycharm.vmoptions
pycharm[13752]: Done
pycharm[13752]: Processing VMOptions file at /Users/myusername/Library/Preferences/PyCharm40/pycharm.vmoptions
pycharm[13752]: No content found
pycharm[13752]: Processing VMOptions file at 
pycharm[13752]: No content found
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.jetbrains.pycharm.382864[13752]) Service exited with abnormal code: 6
```

I looked, and there is no pycharm.vmoptions in ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm40/

What to do?

(thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was simply that you can't run both community and professional edition *at the same time*. You can have them both on your machine, but can only run one or the other at a moment.

I closed CE, then opened pro and it runs fine. Then I tried to open CE with pro running, and it failed in the same way.

The devil's in the details.